What is correct to say both of their sakes/sake?
I'm trying to explain something that is good for two groups of women.

Can you maybe provide a full sentence/passage? And are you talking about the sake of the group collectively or of the individuals separately? With individuals, either variant seems fine, although it's hard to get exact figures because "both of their sake(s)" is rare and "for their sake" could be singular "their". But with collective sakes of multiple groups, results may be different.
